# How to match the 2d array datatype between swift and objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am calling a .mm (objective-c / c++) class method from my swift viewController via linked headers. They are successfully linked. However, I am struggling to pass correct data types that match as parameters. 
Here is where I call the function in swift

```
OpenCVWrapper.thefunc(array1, otherstuff);
```

..`.array1` is of type `[[Int]]`

and here is the definition in objective-c

```
+(NSString*) thefunc: (int[][2])array1 otherstuff(int)other{
```

but i get the error

```
Cannot convert value of type '[[Int]]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablepointer<(Int32)(Int32)>!'
```

My question is, **how can I match the data types so they both handle a basic 2D array of type Int?**

UPDATE:

**value  / structure issues:**

structure passed from swift:

[image]

structure received in OC:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may need to know that C-array and Swift `Array` are different things. C-array represents a contiguous region of memory and uses the **pointer** to the first element when passed.

Second, if you want to use imported Objective-C method from Swift, you'd better check the generated header of the method.

(Press the "four square icon" and choose "Generated Interface" while editor is showing the .h file.)

Tested with a small sample project, your method is imported as:

```
open class func thefunc(_ array1: UnsafeMutablePointer<(Int32, Int32)>!, otherstuff other: Int32) -> String!
```

(The corresponding type to `int` in Swift is `Int32`, not `Int`.)

So, you may need to pass a mutable pointer to tuple `(Int32, Int32)`, to do that you need to declare a Swift `Array` of Element type `(Int32, Int32)` and pass it as an inout argument (using `&`).

So, you may need to write something like this:

```
//Assuming all inner Array of `array1` have two elements.
var convertedArray = array1.map {(Int32($0[0]), Int32($0[1]))}
MyClass.thefunc(&convertedArray, otherstuff: someInt32Value)
```

---

But the conversion of huge array may take some amount of time, in some cases, which is critical.

You may declare your Swift side `array1` as `Array` of `(Int32, Int32)` and modify other parts according to this change, and use it as:

```
//Somewhere in your code...
var array1: [(Int32, Int32)] = []

//...

//And call `thefunc` as:
MyClass.thefunc(&array1, otherstuff: someInt32Value)
```

Comment: really appreciate the in depth answer, and am going to experiment tomorrow with it - will get back to you. Cheers.

Comment: Working on it now. Why `[(Int32, Int32)]` instead of `[[Int32]]` ? Cheers

Comment: @harrylakins, As I wrote, C-array is a contiguous region of memory. But in Swift, `[Int32]` actually is a struct containing an indirect reference to an object which works as a variable sized array. The memory representation is completely different. So, Swift imports fixed sized C-array as Swift tuple, which puts each element in a contiguous region.

Comment: got it. cheers. Another problem: I have updated so that the input is [(Int32, Int32)], but when I dry run the method (in OC), array1 only appears to have 2 values - but when I dry run the function call (in swift) it has what it should - 9 (9 of 2) @OOPer

Comment: @harrylakins, I cannot say any more without seeing your "dry run" code. Please update your question including that info.

Comment: @harrylakins, in Objective-C side, `int [][2]` is equivalent to `int (*)[2]` as shown, a pointer to the first element, the element is an array of two sub-elements. The C-array `int[][2]` has no length information, so the debugger is just showing the first element, which is made of two sub-elements -- two `int`s. I believe `pxVals[1]`...`pxVals[8]` contain the values you passed from Swift side.

Comment: Your right! Thank you very much. As a side question - I cannot seem to use .size() to find the length - how should I?

Comment: @harrylakins, do you mean total byte size? or a number of elements of the Swift `Array`?

Comment: Number of elements

Comment: @harrylakins, then `array1.count` in Swift side.

Comment: ah sorry i meant on objc side

Comment: @harrylakins, no way to retrieve a number of elements from the pointer to the first element, even if you call it directly from Objective-C side. You need to pass that info with another parameter.

Comment: Welcome, happy if I could be some help of you. Good luck for you and for your app.